# Find inside of UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I'm having hard time while trying to search inside of UIWebView. I know that I need to use javascript for that but almost everything I found uses replacing the HTML code and searching by element.type. My HTML file is so big that it's not possible to use this approach and honestly I don't need highlighting. Could anyone help me to write down the javascript code?

Answer (score 1):

Here you will get the answer

http://www.icab.de/blog/2010/01/12/search-and-highlight-text-in-uiwebview/comment-page-1/#comments